# How to change file path for testing function in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

In my `config.py` I define:

```py
import os
from some_file import PROJECT_PATH 
DATA_FILES = os.getenv("DATA_FILES", f"{PROJECT_PATH}/data/elements")
```

In another `.py`, I have written a function, let's say:

```py
def function_1():
   file_path = f'{DATA_FILES}/Image_{file_id}_{i + 1}.png
```

In a `.py` file with Pytest tests:

```py
from project_file import config
def test_function(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(config, "DATA_FILES", f" 
        {PROJECT_PATH}/tests/test_data/file_1")
    print(config.DATA_FILES)
    function_1()
```

When I check printed path that `monkeypatch` should have passed to `function_1`, I get changed value "{PROJECT_PATH}/tests/test_data/file_1". However, it is not passed to the `function_1` which uses the original path still. Do you know any idea why and how to improve the code? Is there a more convenient way of changing variables in Pytests than monkeypatching?

Comment: Please read [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) in the docs.

Comment: Why not make `function_1()` take a parameter for the file path? It's frequently easier to change your code to make it testable than to try to bend it out of shape with monkeypatching.